# Kendo Gauge bind to XML/JSON Datasource

Tags: jquery, xml, json, datasource, kendo-ui

Does anyone have an example of how to bind a Kendo Gauge to an XML or JSON datasource?

Answer (score 1):

You can try in `ajax` with `json` response:

```
...
success: function(data){
   $("#mygauge").data("kendoLinearGauge").value(data.yourValue);
}
...
```